# Laravel hidden form field model binding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, model-binding

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and looking for a solution to inject a `Product` model into my controller. The thing is that I get the product's id from a hidden field in a form `POST`ed to a static route `Route::post('/products/check'...`.

This is the content of my form

```
<form action="{{ route('product.check') }}" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="product" class="modal-product" value="some-product-id-injected-with-js" required/>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="form-control-label">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
         value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" required/>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
</form>
```

And I'd like to have a controller method like this:

```
public function check(Request $request, Product $product) {
 /*...*/
}
```

Where `$product` is mapped to the id of the hidden field in the form and then I would extract the email from `$request`.

I was thinking on some middleware but I don't know if it's the best solution(and I don't know how to do it via middleware) because I don't really understand how DI and the IoC container work behind the scenes. I just used route-model binding via route wildcards before.

Comment: look into this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara I already used this before but it's not what I'm looking for because my route is static(`products/check`), there are no parameters or wildcards that could be dynamical.. I want to have the same route but to be able to "check" all products and for this I made a form in which a hidden field gives me the id of the product to check

Comment: Is it necessary for you to inject the `Product` model ? you can get the product id from the `$request` and do something like `Product::findOrFail($request->product)`

Comment: Yes, that's right but it would make my controller a little bit cleaner and straightforward. It's not a must but I would like to find a way to do this now that I met this problem